# Free tier of Google cloud Not giving outgoing bandwidth properly

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using a free tier of  google cloud server of ubuntu 16.04 ,and I am not getting the outgoing bandwidth properly.Incoming bandwith is good but outgoing bandwidth is not more than 3-4 kbps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only limit to egress of the free tier Compute Instance that I am aware of is the restriction on how much data is send, not the speed of that data, that limit is the 1 GB network egress from North America to all region destinations per month (excluding China and Australia).

Egress throughput caps are handled at the Network level in GCP, [there is more information on this here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#egress_throughput_caps).

Otherwise it may just be an issue with the set-up of your instance.